# Почему не работает .insertBefore

Tags: javascript

```js
'use strict';

let menuItem = document.querySelectorAll("body > header > nav > ul.menu > li.menu-item");
// console.log(menuItem.length); 4
let parentNode = document.querySelectorAll("body > header > nav > ul.menu");
// console.log(parentNode.length); 1
// console.log(menuItem); Ok
parentNode.insertBefore(menuItem[2], menuItem[0].nextSibling);
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
     <nav>
       <ul class="menu">
         <li class="menu-item">Первый пункт</li>
         <li class="menu-item">Третий пункт</li>
         <li class="menu-item">Второй пункт</li>
         <li class="menu-item">Четвертый пункт</li>
       </ul>
     </nav>
   </header>
 </body>
```

**В чем ошибка в коде? По выводам консоли понимаю, что .insertBefore не срабатывает. Задача изменить ранжир строк меню на правильный.**

Comment: Потому что parentNode — это массив (точнее NodeList, но не суть), а у массива никакого insertBefore не существует

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let parentNode = document.querySelector/*All*/("body > header > nav > ul.menu");
```

Comment: ДА! Спасибо!!!!